# Shopware PWA: Disable buying Product before it is Released

Tags: progressive-web-apps, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

Is there a way to disable a product for buying before the release date.

We added a release date for a product, the product has also an available stock. By doing this it is possible to add the product to the cart and buy it. Even if the release date is still in the future. The reason is that the product should automatically become availalbe when the release date (time) is reached, without the requirement to update the stock or anything.
Also disableing the product is no option, because it should be shown as coming soon.

The question is about how to disable it in a shopware-pwa setup, the store should not be allowed to add products to a chart nor to sell them before the release date. Disabeling this on the UI side only does not solve the problem because bots/scripts would still be able to do it by calling the API.

I did not find a setting for this. Does it require to update the logic of the shop?

Comment: As you said, I think this is not only a UI-problem, so not shopware-pwa exclusive.
I suggest you have a look at the add-to-cart api-route in Shopware and try to find a reference to the release date there. If you do not find one, you should be able to locate an event to use in a event-subscriber to add this behaviour yourself. I'll try to give you some more hints later today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To secure this server-side you could register your own data collector for the cart and validate the line item in there. Then if the release date has not yet been reached, you can add an error and prevent the product from being added to the cart. It's important to have this collect the data after the `ProductCartProcessor`, hence the priority lower than `5000`, otherwise the release date won't be available in the payload.

```xml
<service id="Foo\MyPlugin\Content\Product\Cart\CustomCartCollector">
    <tag name="shopware.cart.collector" priority="4999"/>
</service>
```

```php
class CustomCartCollector implements CartDataCollectorInterface
{
    public function collect(CartDataCollection $data, Cart $original, SalesChannelContext $context, CartBehavior $behavior): void
    {
        foreach ($original->getLineItems() as $lineItem) {
            $releaseDate = $lineItem->getPayloadValue('releaseDate');
            if (!$releaseDate) {
                continue;
            }

            $releaseDate = new \DateTime($releaseDate);
            $now = new \DateTime();
            if ($releaseDate > $now) {
                $original->addErrors(new ProductNotFoundError($lineItem->getLabel() ?: $lineItem->getId()));

                $original->getLineItems()->remove($lineItem->getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So I had a quick look and I didn't find any reference to the releaseDate in the `/store-api/checkout/cart/line-item` route either.
But what you can do is to add a subscriber to the `BeforeLineItemAddedEvent` and make that check there yourself. You'd want to throw an exception here, if the releaseDate for the product hasn't been reached yet.
Here is a little example of such a subscriber:

```
class ReleaseDateSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeLineItemAddedEvent::class => 'onLineItemAdded'
        ];
    }
    
    public function onLineItemAdded(BeforeLineItemAddedEvent $event): void
    {
        $lineItem = $event->getLineItem();
        $productId = $lineItem->getId();
        $context = $event->getContext();
        
        /** @var ProductEntity $product */
        $product = $this->productRepository->search(new Criteria([$productId]), $context)->first();
        
        $releaseDate = $product->getReleaseDate();
        // Do what you want with the release date
        $releaseDateReached = true;
        
        if(!$releaseDateReached){
            throw new ProductNotReleasedException();
        }
    }
}
```

For the UX it would obviously be nice to hide the "Add to cart"-button if the product hasn't been released yet, but you mentioned that already so I assume you can help yourself for this.

Comment: I still think this is the better option, however It was never triggered, I added the subscriber in the : 
`  <service id="<company-name>\<plugin-name>\Subscriber\MySubscriber">
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>`
So I switched to using the other solution

Comment: Just to be sure: you did provide the entity-repository as an argument to the service, did you? Because you didn't write it here like this.

Comment: Yes If forgot to copy that part, I had it like this. <argument type="service" id="product.repository" />, but maybe this is not correct, like this?

Comment: This looks correct. Strange that the event doesn't get triggered at all, do you use the standard store-api endpoints? Because if you have a look at `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\SalesChannel\CartItemAddRoute::add` you can see that the event gets triggered there

Comment: Yes I use the standard store-api, I set different breakpoints one in the constructor and one in the onLineItemAdded function, the constructor gets called, but the onLineItemAdded never hit. I assume it is somewhere a really dump error. But I did not find out how to add more logging/debugging the get to the root cause. I will check the CartItemAddRoute as you suggested, maybe I will find something there.

Comment: Okay, this is a bit older already but I came across it again with a bit more knowledge, and now I found the reason why it did not trigger the subscriber. My ID was not properly setup so it did not tell me I was missing an import.
I forgot to import the Event itself, thus it was never triggered...

`use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Event\BeforeLineItemAddedEvent;`